# Replace spaces and ampersands with an underscore

Tags: str-replace

I am attempting to loop through some variables and replace any instance of a space or an `&` with an underscore. I have it working for spaces, how would I go about adding the `&` as well?

```js
$(function() {
  $('div').each(function() {
    var str = $(this).text(),
        str = str.replace(/\s+/g, '_').toLowerCase();
        
    console.log(str);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Testing</div>
<div>Testing This</div>
<div>Testing &amp; This</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this: [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), especially take a look at "character sets", with which you can write your regex like this:

```
str.replace(/[\s&]+/g, '_')
```

So anything inside the character class will be matched, not just spaces.

Notice with this expression you are replacing multiple occurrences of & and spaces by a  single underscore, so:

```
"hello&&&&&&&world"
```

becomes:

```
"hello_world"
```

If that is not what you want, then don't use the `+`:

```
str.replace(/[\s&]/g, '_')
```

so `"hello&&&&&&&world"` becomes:

```
"hello_______world"
```